# Node.js: GET Request returns 404 Not Found

Tags: node.js, rest, express, get

Was working on creating a REST API using Node.js and [Express](http://expressjs.com/). The server starts at `localhost:xxxx` but `localhost:xxxx/bits` returns a 404 Not Found error.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/bits', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Bits called");
});

app.get('/bits/:id', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Bits ID called");
});

app.listen(xxxx);
console.log('Listening on port xxxx.');
```

Help?

Comment: Since there's nothing wrong with the route or the simple code, it seems most likely that your server isn't actually running on the port your accessing or isn't running at all.  Are you, by any chance, trying to run on a low number port that you don't have permissions to run on?

Comment: The server is running for sure. I tried this:

`var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(83, 'localhost');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:83/');`
It printed Hello World.

Comment: I just figured out that this server runs for `127.0.0.1:83` but not for `localhost:83`. My system32 host file has `127.0.0.1 localhost`. What could be the reason?

Comment: On that computer, try this `ping -4 localhost` in a command window and see what IP address it thinks localhost is.

Comment: It returns the same, 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran your code but with replacing xxxx with a port number.  It worked fine for me.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/bits', function(req, res) {
    res.send([{name:'bit1'}, {name:'bit2'}]);
});

app.get('/bits/:id', function(req, res) {
    res.send({id:req.params.id, name: "The Name", description: "description"});
});

app.listen(8080);
console.log('Listening on port 8080.');
```

I ran the some curl commands as well to show it working.

```
[09:24 AM] jsloyer@Jeffs-MacBook-Pro [Downloads]>curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/bits
[{"name":"bit1"},{"name":"bit2"}]
[09:25 AM] jsloyer@Jeffs-MacBook-Pro [Downloads]>curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/bits/1
{"id":"1","name":"The Name","description":"description"}
[09:25 AM] jsloyer@Jeffs-MacBook-Pro [Downloads]>
```

Additionally [here is](https://github.com/jsloyer/stackoverflow-question-29987564) a whole Node.js git project including the source for it.

You can click the button below to deploy it as well to see it in action.

[image: Deploy to Bluemix]

Comment: By xxxx I meant port number of course. Some other way to check about the possible error(s)?

Comment: What version of node are you running and what version of express?

Comment: Node.js: 0.12.2
Express: 3.20.2

Comment: Try pulling down the git project i posted to see if that works.  I posted the example with express 4.x but it shouldnt matter, you arent doing anything that really matters between the two versions.